# SHGetFolderPath() 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: winapi, shell, 64-bit, path, 32-bit

What happens if I use [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api call in a 32 bit system with CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESx86 folder id instead of the CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES id?

Theoretically CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESx86 should map to `C:\program files (x86)` in a 64 bit system but what does it map to in a 32 bit system where this path doesn't exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The different scenarios are described in [this article on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb762584(v=vs.85)).

The interpretation of certain `KNOWNFOLDERID` values depends on whether the folder is part of a 32-bit or 64-bit application and whether that application is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system. If your application needs to distinguish between, for example, `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`, you must use the right `KNOWNFOLDERID` for the situation.

The following table summarizes the `KNOWNFOLDERID` use in those cases.

| OS | App | KNOWNFOLDERID | Default Path | CSIDL Equivalent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFiles | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES |
| 32 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 |
| 32 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 | Not applicable | Not applicable |
| 64 bit | 64 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFiles | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES |
| 64 bit | 64 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86) | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 |
| 64 bit | 64 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | None |
| 64 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFiles | %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86) | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES |
| 64 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86) | CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 |
| 64 bit | 32 bit | FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 | %SystemDrive%\Program Files | None |

Summary: It will point to %SystemDrive%\Program Files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432", szBuffer, nBufferSize);
```

YMMV