# HSQLDB lock file in programs and files - file directory write permission

Tags: java, windows, hibernate, security, hsqldb

I have an application in JAVA that connects to HSQLDB and need to be installed, i made that app and works fine, but when i put my code on the Programs and files folder, the HSQLDB cannot edit the lock property and cannot open the software =(

i know that is Windows security, but, is there a way to make the folder who contain my database editable?(c:programs and files\mySoftware\database) Like in PHP, using chmod...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong approach. Instead of making a folder editable, you need to put your files to application-specific folder under \Users\All users\AppData\yourapplication (in Windows 7) or \Users\Profilename\AppData\yourapplication folder. The path to this folder is obtained via Windows API (don't know what Java offers in regards to Windows-specific API, sorry) function named [SHGetFolderPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138379/shgetfolderpath-32-bit-vs-64-bit). You need CSIDL_APPDATA or CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA paths there.

Comment: The HSQLDB file path can reference the Java user.home directory with a "~" symbol. For example "jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/yourapplcation/yourdb"